# how to show missing value row before categorical levels or continuous statistics in gtsummary?

Tags: r, gtsummary

so gtsummary has this useful fucntion tbl_summary().
by default, it shows the missing value row after levels of a categorical variable or after statistics of a continuous variable.
I want to have the variable name and p-value in one row, and then the rest of the statistics in rows below it in a way that missing values even if they are zero to be shown in the first row followed by the rest of the statistics for that variable.
I read the documentation and I could not find such option. in fact I am able to add {N-miss} for continuous variable using the continuous2 argument however I did not manage to find something like that for categorical variables. is there any trick to do so?

```
 df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1:3, NA),
                  col2 = c("this", NA,"is", "text"), 
                  col3 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), 
                  col4 = c(2.5, 4.2, 3.2, NA),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df %>% tbl_summary(by = col3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use `modify_table_body` to reorder the table body such that the rows with the missings are positioned before the rows with the categories or levels or after the first row with the label:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c(1:3, NA),
  col2 = c("this", NA, "is", "text"),
  col3 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE),
  col4 = c(2.5, 4.2, 3.2, NA)
)

df %>%
  tbl_summary(by = col3) |>
  modify_table_body(fun = ~ .x %>%
    mutate(row_type = forcats::fct_relevel(row_type, "missing", after = 1)) |>
    arrange(variable, row_type, label))
```

[image]